# On GitLab SaaS, show commits in issues' activity feed

Tags: gitlab

I'm using GitLab SaaS (so, not self-managed), and when pushing commits referencing an issue (by copy/pasting the issue's reference), the commits don't appear in the issues' Activity feeds.

I know my issue reference is OK, because when browsing commits, I can see the reference, it is clickable, and it correctly links to the issue.

I search the docs, the Web, and the settings, but couldn't find anything that helps.

I have another repo (also on GitLab SaaS) that works as expected and shows commits in the issues' activity feeds.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason: I was committing to the repo using an e-mail not listed in the project's members.

I "invited myself" to the repo with that other account and now my commits show as expected.